# The result is coming back correct but not in correct format

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop, range, do-while, sqrt

I am doing an assignment and the answers are coming back correctly but I would need them to say `5! = 120` instead of just `= 120`. How would I go about that?

```
def getInt():
    getInt = int
    done = False

    while not done:
        print("This program calcultes N!")

        # get input for "N
        N = int(input("Please enter a non-negative value for N: "))

        if N < 0:
            print("Non-Negative integers, please!")
        else:
            done = True
        return N

def main():
    n = getInt()

    for i in range(n-1):
        n = n * (i+1)

    print("=" ,n)

main()
```

Comment: `print(n_saved, '! = ', n, sep='')`

Answer (score 0):

can you show me your homework instructions? 
i'm not sure what the first value is in your example.. the current iteration or the original number entered?

```
# declare getInt()
def getInt():

  getInt = int
  done = False

  while not done:

    # write "this program calculates N!"
    print("This program calcultes N!")

    # get input for "N
    N = int(input("Please enter a non-negative value for N: "))

    # if N < 0 then
    if N < 0:

      print("Non-Negative integers, please!")

    # else        
    else:

     # done = true
     done = True

    # return N
    return N

# main
def main():

  n = entry = getInt()

  for i in range(n-1):

    n = n * (i+1)

  print("{0}! = {1}".format(entry, n))

main()
```

results:

```
/*
This program calcultes N!
Please enter a non-negative value for N: 5
5! = 120
*/
```

Comment: It's finding factorials when I run the program and enter 5 it gives me back 120 which is the factorial of 5 but I need it in a format that says "5! = 120" can you show me how you got 5! = 7200?

Comment: @KobeYazzie i see what you mean. updated the code to show that.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this code will help.
    `print('Enter a positive integer')
    a = int(input())
    def factorial(n):
        if n == 0:
            return(1)
        if n == 1:
            return(1)
        if n > 1:
            return(n * factorial(n-1))
    if a < 0:
        print('Non-Negative integers, please!')
    if a >= 0:
        print(str(a) + '! = ' + str(factorial(a)))`

Answer (score 0):

In the `for i in range(n-1)`you could use another integer instead of n just to be sure things don't mess up and you can print like joel said `print(i,"!=", n)` but instead of n the integer you will use.